# dependency injection not working in data class "an object reference is required" error

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, ado.net, inversion-of-control

I have a c# DotNet6 project where I need to get my connection string from within my data classes, and usually did this via a global variable.  I need to do this via dependency injection instead, and got the injection to work in my class, however, I can't use a property (in this case a simple string) of it without the "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property ..." error message in the IDE.  I'm not sure what I am doing incorrectly (and the following code was lifted from a tutorial for dotnetcore 2.0 - clearly something changed).

In my program.cs, I have created a class called DBconfig and the builder options, as so:

```
public class DBConfig
{
    public string ConnString { get; set; } = "";
}


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(options => options.EnableQueryFeatures());
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new DBConfig() { ConnString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConn") });

var app = builder.Build();
```

In my data class, I have the following private property and constructor, for database methods inside:

```
 public class LiveItem_Data
    {
        private readonly DBConfig _conf;

        public LiveItem_Data(DBConfig conf)
        {
            _conf = conf;
        }
```

When I use _conf.ConnString inside my SqlConnection, I get the squiggly line, "_conf is not null here" and error "An object reference is required for the non-static field..." .

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new(_conf.ConnString))
```

So I figured I'd make the ConnString static, but then in the program.cs, but then I can't use it in the object initializer (since it's static - of course), and tried other things, but keep going in circles.  Like the DI part works, but I can't seem to configure it so I can actually use it.

Comment: "An object reference is required for the non-static field..." implies that your code was `DBConfig.ConnString`.  "I get the squiggly line, "_conf is not null here" maybe you needed `!.`, unless there was an error too?

Comment: I'm still new to this. What do you mean by the exclamation point? The error _conf is not null, makes no sense - of course it's not null - it should be a string!!!

Comment: Add a line and a breakpoint on it to check if your configuration is reading the connection string from the appsettings.json; `var checkString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConn")`

Comment: if you wish to use your `LiveItem_Data` with DI, inject it into your service container too. `builder.Services.AddSingleton<LiveItem_Data>();`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to somehow replicate your setup and I've created from scratch a .NET core API (c# 10/ .NET 6).

Here is my setup:
Program.cs:

```
using WebApplication1;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new DBConfig() { ConnString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConn") });


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

appsettings.config:

```
   {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBConn": "Server=localhost;Database=TestDb;"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

and default generated controller where I have injected the config:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
        private readonly DBConfig _config;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, DBConfig config)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _config = config;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()

        {
            //check connection string
            using (SqlConnection conn = new(_config.ConnString))
            {

            }

            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't see any error related to the null evaluation and the config value is passed correctly:

[image]

Maybe this example will help a bit, or maybe you could add some extra details to your question (like how is the LiveItem_Data registered with DI, or created)

Comment: Well, it is possible to add the .net core DI into console app, by using  "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" nuget and at the Program.cs level something like this:   var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<IBarService, BarService>()
            .BuildServiceProvider(); However, there is no auto-injection, you need to define it for all your objects.

Comment: In your WeatherForecast example, where you are making a database call directly in your controller and DI is working, why you can't do that in a separate area of your application?  I don't want to make direct calls to the DB from any controller. This makes no sense..

Comment: yes, that's true, was a simple example, however, if you need to inject your config into a service or dataclass then you need to register that class into the DI. So,a common business application would look like this: Controller -> Service -> Repository. If all those parts are registered in the DI and by all parts I mean the service and the repository, then you can use directly the Configuration object in the constructor of the Repository. this is how the DI understands what to build. Controllers are part of the DI automatically. If one of the classes is not registered with the DI, it won't work

Comment: see @Lee answes, LiveItem_Data is registed as well as Singleton and it works, because the  DI knows the full object tree and knows how to build those objects by injecting values (transient, scoped or singleton)

Comment: Technically, it's the wrong answer - it works because it's in the controller. I don't wish to make database calls straight from the controller - I wish to use DI in a class that is called by a controller (or whatever).  

Here is an example of how I make a call from my controller:

             
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(int pg = 0, int recs = 10)
        {
            List<LiveItem> items = await LiveItem_Data.GetLiveItemsByPageSortAsync("", recs, pg);
            if (!items.Any()) return NotFound();
            return Ok(items);
        }

Comment: I understand that, but where is your LiveItem_Data registration in the DI ?? You are missing that bit... that's what I am trying to tell you.

Comment: I tried that, but it only works inside the controller, but I don't want nor need the connection string in the controller. The controller calls LiveItem_Data.GetLiveItems ... 
to get the results it needs. I suppose I could change the GetLiveItems method to accept a connection string as a parameter and do this for every get/put/post/delete method (50 or so, in all) and make a really sloppy mess of things.

Comment: @MC9000 I don’t understand your comment, you don’t need the connection string in the controller, you can just call live_data.getLiveItems directly as it already has the DbConfig injected

Comment: If you looked at my example and screenshots, I didn’t call or inject the connection string, it’s already resolved in the class. So I inject the service class into the controller and when I make a db call within the service class it works

Comment: I don't want the connection string in the controller - ever (bad practice, for starters). I want it in the DB class.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection works for the request pipeline, it will not work for any class you may want to use. This would happen usually in controllers or razor pages. Once you capture the injected object there, you can add it to your variable declaration. For instance with controllers, you may want to do something like this, and your startup code would be unchanged from the looks for it

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private DBConfig _conf;

    public HomeController(DBConfig conf)
    {
        _conf = conf;
    }

    public IActionResult Index() 
    {
        LiveItem_Data myclass = new LiveItem_Data(_conf)
        myclass.dostuff();
        //Do whatever


    }

}
```

I think if you follow the pattern of taking what injected into the request pipeline from the constructor of the controller (a bit diff if you are using razor pages) it should work fine.

Comment: you can do so as long as the class is also injected into the service container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add both to the service container if you wish your classes to resolve its dependencies via DI

```
using WebApplication1.Model;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
// add dbconfig
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new DbConfig() { ConnString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConn") });
// add data layer
builder.Services.AddSingleton<LiveItem_Data>();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

use it like this

```
private LiveItem_Data _myClass;
public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, LiveItem_Data myClass)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _myClass = myClass;

}

// now this will work because the dbConfig will be resolved
// in LiveItem_Data
[HttpGet] public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(int pg = 0, int recs = 10) 
{ 
    List<LiveItem> items = await LiveItem_Data
        .GetLiveItemsByPageSortAsync("", recs, pg); 
    if (!items.Any()) return NotFound(); return Ok(items); 
}
```

[image]

If you're still getting an error, check your appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBConn": "Server=localhost;Database=TestDb;"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you  mean, this is my answer to this question. I dont see any updates

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a kludge for my data access layer for now.
In program.cs, I just put in a partial class for Program (which is available globally - so it's DI-like) like so:

```
partial class Program { public static string DbConn {get; private set;}=""; }
```

Then grabbed the connection string from the builder and assigned it like so:

```
string _DbConn = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConn");
DbConn = _DbConn;
```

From the data classes, I just use Program.DbConn and voila! as so

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new(Program.DbConn))
```

While this is not the answer I was looking for, I'm posting here as it works well (and don't have to monkey with DI and it's shortcomings). I won't vote this as the answer as someone may ultimately have a way to make this work (outside of request pipelines).